# Why does this javascript class problem occur on iPhone?

Tags: javascript, class, mobile, desktop

I have the following class:

```
class Test{
        var = 'test';

        constructor(){
            alert( this.a );
        }
    }
```

running this in JavaScript:

```
var t = new Test();
```

result in an alert 'test' if I run it on my desktop, even when emulating iPhone, but if I run this on my iPhone I don't get any result.

When I change the class to both mobile and desktop work:

```
class Test{
    constructor(){
        this.a = 'test';
        alert( this.a );
    }
}
```

It seems that initializing, or even merely declaring variables outside the constructor (which should be possible according to [Mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)) breaks classes for mobile devices.

I went on and tried the 'old fashioned' way of defining a class:

```
Test = function( value ){
    var a = 'default';

    this.construct = function( value ){
        a = value;
    }

    this.test = function(){
        alert( a );
    }

    this.construct( value );
};

var t = new Test( 'test' );
t.test();
```

That works like a charm on both mobile and desktop.

Is it safe to assume that classes are buggy on mobile and when programing something responsive that needs to run on both mobile and desktop are better with the 'old-school' way of 'making a class' than using 'Class', or is something else the matter?

I created this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v2p5cjna/) that runs on desktop, but not on mobile.

Comment: What version of iOS is the iPhone running?

Comment: Instance variables in class declarations is a fairly new language feature; it's not supported in all environments.

Comment: IPhone X with 12.4. Tried an old iPhone 5c with 10.3.3 as well

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) public class field declarations are not supported by any version of Safari (or IE or Edge).

Comment: @Pointy, it’s introduced in 2015. I had my doubts of using classes for browser support reasons, but after 4 years the latest iOS doesn’t seem to support this. I would expect all OS’s to have the same Class interpretation. I’m developing on Mac OS as well, there Chrome has no problems

Comment: Yes it was introduced a while ago, but it's still a Stage 3 Proposal as far as I know.

Comment: @Pointy, clear! Don’t use public class field declarations as in the first example of my question. That’s good to know, but tbh kind of surprising. It doesn’t work in Chrome either